# VBScript storing collection resulting from regex matching a file collection into array

Tags: collections, vbscript

I want to access RegEx results after I am done moving files with this script. (For example: I want to later send the names of files that matched regex pattern to my E-mail)

Problem is: Can't use "objFile.Name" outside of the initial file moving loop that I get during regex. This should have been possible using the "Execute" method for RegEx, but unfortunately I can't get it to work on a collection resulting from "GetFolder().Files", it works for me only on single strings.

Only Test method worked for me initially, and it works OK for initial file moving, but then I get runtime errors when I cannot access the "objFile" object later.

My latest attempt to try to write resulting matches into array also don't work, error is:

**Line 26, 3**

**Object doesn't support this property or method:**

'SubMatches'

Here's the latest attempt at getting this code to work:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strDumpStorageDir = "C:\"

strShareDirectory = "E:\"

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strShareDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files


Set re = New RegExp
re.Global     = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Pattern    = "fs"

Dim matches()
Dim i: i = 0

For Each objFile in colFiles

 bMatch = re.Test(objFile.Name)
   If bMatch Then
    objFS.MoveFile strShareDirectory & objFile.Name , strDumpStorageDir
   End If
  ReDim preserve matches(i)
  Matches(i) = objFile.SubMatches(0)
  i = (i + 1)


Next

   For i = 0 to uBound(Matches)
   wscript.echo Matches(i)
Next



WScript.Quit
```

Comment: RegExp seems like overkill for what you are doing here.  Is there a particular reason you're not using string functions?

Comment: You cannot `Execute()` a RegExp on a collection, you can only do this on a string, so you have to iterate through all files. I agree with Nilpo, why don't you use `If Instr(objFile.Name, "fs") Then ...` in this case?

Comment: Perhaps I should have included more info on my ultimate goal in the first place. "fs" is only a sample pattern, e.g. simplest that would work. In reality there will be plenty of other stuff in this folder and I will need to have to differentiate between filenames like: fs-<servername_here>-<date_here>.<file_extension_here>. Which is why I think that using a string (Which I would not know in advance) is not an option and decided to use RegEx pattern matching instead. Hope that you can understand my certifiably insane solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that (1) you don't have any [submatches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/y27d2s18%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-- a submatch occurs whenever you have something that matches to a parenthesized expression in your pattern (you don't have any parentheses in your pattern)-- and (2) you're trying to refrence the SubMatches collection in the objFile object, not a Matches object.

The edited code here should store the full path of each file you had a match on in the Matches() array.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strDumpStorageDir = "C:\"

strShareDirectory = "E:\"

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strShareDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files


Set re = New RegExp
re.Global     = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Pattern    = "fs"

Dim matches()
Dim curFile
Dim i: i = 0

For Each objFile in colFiles
    bMatch = re.Test(objFile.Name)
    curFile = objFile.Name
    If bMatch Then
        'objFS.MoveFile strShareDirectory & objFile.Name , strDumpStorageDir
        ReDim preserve matches(i)
        Matches(i) = curFile
        i = (i + 1)
    End If
Next

For i = 0 to uBound(Matches)
   wscript.echo Matches(i)
Next

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: You don't have to store the path, because you can also store the object in the array. Change `Matches(i) = curFile` to `Set Matches(i) = objFile` and you can access all properties of the the matched files later on when you iterate the array.

Comment: @ transistor1: Excellent! But I changed `objFile.Path` to `objFile.Name` , Since it produces results like: "E:\fstest1.file" and I needed "fstest1.file" to prefix the results later with new drive name after files get moved to C:\

Comment: @ AutomatedChaos: This worked too, but `Set Matches(i) = objFile` produces the same result as `objFile.Path` (e.g. prepends Drive letter) which is exactly what I was trying to avoid. And I cannot do `Set Matches(i) = objFile.Name` , that will produce a "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: @GSP edited to reflect `.Name`, for your particular circumstance. @AutomatedChaos is saying that if you use the `Set` command, in the loop you could then use `wscript.echo Matches(i).Name`, or access whatever other properties you need. For your purposes, it seems like you are only using the file name after the loop, so you don't really need the object.